# Covert dates to get first day or last day in the month

Tags: javascript, date

I have an object array which contains a start and end date for multiple events. Below is an example of one object in it

```
{
end_date: "2022-07-22T00:00:00.000Z"
name: "Event 1"
start_date: "2021-09-08T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Is there a way to change the start date to the first day in whatever month it is, and the end day to the last day in whatever month it is?

I tried this:

```
dates.start_date.setDate(1);
dates.end_date.setDate(28);
```

but it's saying setDate is not a function

Comment: `setDate` works on `Date` objects. You can convert the strings to dates.

Comment: You have a string, not a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```js
const data = {
  end_date: "2022-07-22T00:00:00.000Z",
  name: "Event 1",
  start_date: "2021-09-08T00:00:00.000Z"
};

const endDate = new Date(data.end_date);
const startDate = new Date(data.start_date);

const result = {
  startOfMonth: new Date(startDate.getUTCFullYear(), startDate.getUTCMonth(), 1),
  endOfMonth: new Date(endDate.getUTCFullYear(), endDate.getUTCMonth() + 1, 0)
};

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Get the First Day of a Month

To get the first day of a month, use the [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) constructor to create a date object, passing it the year, month and 1 for the day as parameters. The Date object will contain the first day of the month.

### Get the Last Day of a Month

To get the last day of a month, use the [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) constructor to create a date object, passing it the year, the month + 1, and 0 for the day as parameters. The Date object will contain the last day of the month.

`Date()` constructor take 3 arguments:

- The year
- The month
- The day

```js
let obj = {
  name: "Event 1",
  start_date: "2021-09-08T00:00:00.000Z",
  end_date: "2022-07-22T00:00:00.000Z",
};
start = new Date(obj.start_date);
end = new Date(obj.end_date);
obj.start_date = new Date(
  start.getFullYear(),
  start.getMonth(),
  1
).toISOString();
obj.end_date = new Date(end.getFullYear(), end.getMonth() + 1, 0).toISOString();
console.log(obj);
```